# How to deal with third party libraries?

Tags: license-compatibility, license-recommendation, bsd

I'm working on a project I would like to release as an open source project in the future. In my work I'm using a number of third party libraries, either from open source projects or released to the public domain. SQLite, Log4Net, OpenJPEG and OpenSSL are four typical examples.

Can I freely distribute the required libraries with my project as long as I include the related licensing documents and how does it influence my own licensing options? I would like to use a BSD licensing model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that *linking* to the library doesn't introduce incompatibilities/extra restrictions. I.e., according to the FSF, just arranging for the program to link against a GPLed library forces the whole to be distributed under GPL (there isn't consensus, nor binding legal precedents). Check he licences *carefully*, ask e.g. here for detailed analysis, and possibly retain a lawyer to look into the matter.